# Is it safe to use boost::lockfree with c++11 thread support library?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, c++11, lock-free

I currently have a code written using C++ 11 thread support library: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread

I am wondering whether it would be safe to mix that code with boost::lockfree. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/lockfree.html

That is, I want multiple C++11 std::threads to concurrently access boost::lockfree::queue.  Probably it would be safer to replace C++11 thread with boost::thread, but if I could minimize the code change it would be nice.

Comment: A short answer is "Probably": every lock free data structure and algorithm I know of do not rely all that heavily on the details of the threading model as much as they rely on processor primitives.  A long answer is "dunno", because this will possibly depend on some deep mojo in your language and boost implementation.  On a platform with lack of concurrency primitives (like CAS), you could imagine a bunch of stuff being implemented through some seriously crazy ways, and `boost` and `std` choosing different crazy ways.  Are you programming on relatively standard hardware?

Comment: Is Portability a concern ? If yes, then you cold use it. If the development is on Windows then you can use Parallel Pattern Libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am currently working on a threadpool implementation myself using a lockfree queue and std::thread however I am using the Joe Seigh atomic queue algorithm rather than the boost version. I can see no reason why the boost version would not be fine, I've examined the source and it seems an excellent implementation to me.